Execute multiple Mono in parallel and combine results without blocking
I am writing a micro-service that calls for a few other microservices.
Some of the services that are being called are independent, while other services are dependent on the response of the previous service. (so I presume we would need chaining).
What I have so far is:
  public class ServiceA {
    
    private Mono<DataBuilder> getDatabuilder() {
    
      Mono<Result1> result1 = getService1();
      Mono<Result2> result2 = getService2();
      Mono<Result3> result3 = getService3();
      Mono<Result4> result4 = getService4();
    
      result4.flatmap(result -> { 
        Mono<Result5> result5 = getService5(result);
        if (!exists(id, result) {
            result5 = getService5(id);  
        }
    
        Mono<Result6> result6 = result5.flatMap(r -> getService6(r));
    
        Mono<Result7> result7 = result6.flatMap(rx -> getService7(rx));
    
        DataBuilder dataBuilder = DataBuilder.builder();
    
        return Flux.merge(result1, result2, result3, result4, result5, result6, result7)
                 .collect(
                           () -> dataBuilder, 
                           (builder, obj) -> createBuilder(builder, obj, context)
                 )
                 .flatMap(b -> Mono.just(b.build()));
    
      });
    }
  }

// createBuilder method looks something like this

private DataBuilder createBuilder(DataBuilder builder, Object obj) {


    if (obj instanceof Result1) {
        builder.result1((Result1) obj);
    } else if (obj instanceof Result2) {
        builder.result2((Result2) obj);
    } else if (obj instanceof Result3) {
        builder.result3((Result3)obj);
    } else if (obj instanceof Result4) {
        builder.result4((Result4) obj);
    } else if (obj instanceof Result5) {
        builder.result5((Result5) obj);
    } else if (obj instanceof Result5) {
        builder.result6((Result6) obj);
    }

    return builder;

}

In my main class I call:
  public class Main() {
    
    ServiceA a = new ServiceA();
    DataBuilder builder = a.getDatabuilder().block();
    
  }

In this case, I have used a blocking call to read DataBuilder once it's ready,  but I do not see any better way to do this since the first 3 services are independent and are being called in parallel. Next, from Service 4 to Service 7, all are dependent on other services or each other.
The DataBuilder obj is then is then passed through a mapper and sent downstream.
Besides the blocking call, I do not see any way to get the output from all the monos without blocking.

This answer should give some insight in terms of how to run CompletableFuture instances whose values don't depend on each in parallel and collect their results. In short, if the values depend on each other, think Monad. If not, think Applicative.

The service 4 to service 7 would still not run in parallel with completableFuture. thenCompose, for example, would still have to wait for a previous service to complete before the next service. so I am not sure if that is the appropriate solution. More over why mix 2 technologies rx-java and CompletableFutures together ?

I wasn't suggesting to use CompletableFuture but just pointing to a general approach. Mono also has map and flatMap, which allows you to implement the same approach directly.

Which language is this? I see a lot of syntax issues and formatting problems if it is Java. It is harder to read and figure out the issue like this.
